# Running MariaDB & MySQL on the same server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb, linux-mint

I would like to test the MariaDB database server on my local computer whilst keeping my existing MySQL server running. This is in preparation for migrating my live websites from MySQL to MariaDB.

Is it possible to install MariaDB on the same system as MySQL? I haven't tried to do an apt-get install mariadb-server yet as everything I have read seems to suggest that the MySQL binaries would be replaced with the MariaDB binaries.

My system:

```
jonny@jrlp01 ~ $ uname -a
Linux jrlp01 3.9.6-030906-generic #201306131535 SMP Thu Jun 13 19:35:54 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

jonny@jrlp01 ~ $ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 15 Olivia
Release:    15
Codename:   olivia

jonny@jrlp01 ~ $ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
```

Comment: It is possible.  Please read this article http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/multiple-servers.html for the answer you are looking for.  You would have to install mariadb on a non-standard directory and run it on a different port.

Comment: Thanks for that link. Would I have to download and build MariaDB rather than use apt-get?

Comment: I do not think apt-get has any option to specify the destination  directory.  So yes, you would have to build MariaDB.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: This seems like a good use for a virtual machine.

Comment: Hmmm - hadn't thought of that. Not sure if my laptop has enough hardware to run a virtual machine. Will investigate.

Comment: Please check MySQL Sandbox - https://github.com/datacharmer/mysql-sandbox

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) technology. It would help you to stand two DB separately. Moreover you can make the buckups (read about docker manager and nodes), and you can open ports just as you want to. At least read about it ;)

edit: P.S it is well using on servers, but on local machines it is a good idea to use VM.

If your local computer cant hadle that, consider using for example AWS DB

**Wrote for future question lookers ;)**

Comment: are there any specific reasons or links you would like to share for your P.S statement? I'm interested in the WHY about it.

Comment: It was 3 years ago. I had several problems with rerouting to the world. It no longer an issue